# Sonar is not starting

Tags: debian, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

After some months off, my SonarQube (4.5) doesn't want to start. I am running on Oracle JDK 1.7 and postgres 9.4.

This is the only thing i get in logs :

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I tried to run sonar in debug with sonar.log.level=DEBUG but no changes.

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Change the logging of the wrapper in wrapper.conf. Look at the wrapper.console.loglevel and the wrapper.logfile.loglevel settings.

Comment: You should check logs/sonar.log too.

Comment: The log on my question is the log on sonar.log

Here is the log with the wrapper loglevel at DEBUG :
http://pastebin.com/2vaLS4Tp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fix it, it was an issue with the ownership.